# Remover Botão e Campo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Existe alguma maneira de remover campos com definitivo em Jquery?

Tenho o código abaixo via Javascript, quando faço um Input gravando a data no banco, necessito que o botão e o input desapareça, permenecendo apenas a data inputada:

```
    <td>
     <?php echo $fetch['data_protocolo']; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
  <input  name="protocolo" id="protocolo" type="text" placeholder="" style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control input-md">
 <br>

  <input id="btn" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="OK" />
  </td>



<script>

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function () {

document.getElementById('protocolo').remove();

 this.remove();
};

</script>
```

O código acima funciona, porem se eu atualizo a pagina, os botões voltam. Teria alguma forma de remover os campos de forma definitiva?

Comment: O `<?php echo $fetch['data_protocolo']; ?>` é vazio inicialmente, antes de vc fazer o submit?

Comment: Existe uma estrutura em While que traz todas as informações do banco. Inicialmente o campo Data de Protocolo é vazio, e posteriormente preenchido. Uma vez preenchido, necessito que os elementos sumam (Input Text e Submit). E os que não foram preenchidos, permanecem.

Comment: Não basta somente desaparecer com o input e o botão, deveria também evitar nova conexão.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz uma nova `request` ele vai recarregar os elementos novamente! Ou seja o `DOM` vem como se fosse a primeira vez que carrega esse conteúdo. O que é o comportamento esperado nesse código.
Uma sugestão: faça uma estrutura que altere algum valor flag, que você possa verificar toda vez que recarrega a página! 
Ao VERIFICAR se o mesmo está como true ou false, você pode determinar se deve aparecer ou não. Você pode abordar diversas estratégias para isso: Valores na `session`, um consumo de `API´s,` etc etc etc.

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei. Grato @Tiago

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ocultar a parte do HTML (campo e botão) caso o valor em `$fetch['data_protocolo'];` não esteja vazio:

```
<td>
   <?php
   echo $fetch['data_protocolo'];
   if(empty($fetch['data_protocolo'])){
   ?>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input  name="protocolo" id="protocolo" type="text" placeholder="" style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control input-md">
   <br>
   <input id="btn" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="OK" />
   <?php
   }
   ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Além de fazer desaparecer o botão e o input, permanecendo apenas a data inputada, seria importante evitar nova conexão ao banco usando `$_SESSION`

Parti do pressuposto que na tabela existe algum dado único ( no exemplo abaixo seria o email )

1. verifique se existe uma session, se não existir session e o form não for submetido só imprimir na tela o formulário
2. se não existir session, verifique se o formulário foi submetido
3. se não existir session e o form for submetido verificar se existe o email, se existir informar a existência deste
4. se não existir faça o insert e crie uma session

**Código**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["insert"]==""){

   if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");
      $email=$_POST['email'];
      $data_protocolo=$_POST['protocolo'];
      $sql2=("SELECT * FROM tabela where email='$email'");
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);

        while($fetch= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $data_protocolo=$fetch['data_protocolo'];
          echo $data_protocolo;
          $resultEmail=$fetch['email'];
        }
        if ($resultEmail==""){
           $mysqli->query("Insert into tabela (email,data_protocolo) values ('$email','$data_protocolo')");
           $_SESSION["insert"] = $data_protocolo;
        }else{
           echo "<br>email ".$resultEmail." já existente";
        } 
   }

}

if($_SESSION["insert"]==""){
?> 
   <form role="form" id="meuForm" action="" method="post">
   <input  name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control input-md" value="" required> 
   <input  name="protocolo" id="protocolo" type="date" placeholder="" style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control input-md" value="" required>
   <br>
   <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="OK" />
   </form>
<?php 
}else{
  echo $_SESSION["insert"];
}
?>
```